# Docking with QWinWidget: Adding DockWidgetAreas to QWidgets

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have an application utilizing `QWinWidget` in a Win32 window. I'd like to add DockWidgets and the associated behaviour to it. There don't seem to be any exposed APIs for adding custom `DockAreas`, and the latest docs are sparse beyond adding `DockWidgets` to a `QMainWindow`. [Older docs imply](http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qdockarea.html) there once was a public `QDockArea` class.

So far, my best option appears to be [adding a neutered QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273639/custom-dock-area-using-qt-4-4/1275448#1275448) (no top-level status, no frame, etc.) to the QWinWidget and going from there ([second source](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-37591.html)).

I was hoping there was a way to add DockAreas to any container, but it doesn't appear that way. As a side note, `QWinWidget` is used to have window manager control with our custom frame requirement, but if there's a pure `QMainWindow`/`QWidget` way to have the same result (with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`), I'd be happy to switch over.

Comment: I'm going the QMainWindow as a child way... and it's really painless. Mysteriously painless, even...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I've added within my QWinWidget in my Win32 window a QMainWindow field. That is:

```
class QWinWidget : public QWidget
{
  ...
  QMainWidget* mainWidget;
}

QWinWidget::QWinWidget()
{
  mainWidget = new QMainWindow(this);
  mainWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget); //1
}
```

Note that while [the](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#QMainWindow) [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) and [some](https://forum.qt.io/topic/31841/qmainwindow-inside-a-widget-can-be-done-or-is-not-correct/9) [forum posts](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12569-QMainWindow-as-a-child-of-QMainWindow) ([from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917115/floating-sub-qmainwindow-qmainwindow-as-child-widget-of-main-qmainwindow)) indicate you need to set window flags explicitly due to the QMainWindow constructor setting `Qt::Window`, I tested it without the `setWindowFlags()` line (marked with `//1` above) without noticing anything wrong.

So, this gives me the nice QWinWidget window I spent so much time making, inside a frameless Win32 window, with a QMainWindow child and all the features that brings along with it. Docking, menu bar, status bar, etc.